# Can't launch or install Libre writer or office

Tags: libreoffice

I can't open or even install the Libre office or word writer in my `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS` 64 bit system.
I get the following error message when I tried to uninstall and reinstall it back as I couldn't find enough resources online to troubleshoot.

```
Unable to install "LibreoFfice Writer" as download failed:
E: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libreoffice-writer amd64 1:6.4.7-Oubuntu0.20.04.6 is not (yet) available (Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.33 81])
```

Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks

N.B.: the IP in the error message was changed by me for privacy.

Comment: Looks like out of disk space? Please paste the full output in the question of the following commands. No need to redact the IP, it's the IP of the repository server, and they're publicly, well known. `df -h`, `sudo apt update`, `apt-cache policy libreoffice-writer`

Comment: @popey I did a bit of investigation, it is like you said, disk space issue. Please refer to the question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459129/huion-graphic-tablet-driver-filling-up-syslog that is the reason I am having problems with libre.