# Huion graphic tablet driver filling up syslog

Tags: drivers, syslog

I uninstalled all the files and .sh extensions from huion graphic tablet, but my `/var/log/syslog` file are reaching upto 50-60GB in days and I am reaching to the limit.

I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490004/)
which worked with syslog.1 but syslog is still full of huion stuff.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue. The logging seems to be hard-coded within the **huiontablet** executable (located within /usr/lib/huiontablet/ on my system).

The solution I found was to configure rsyslog to filter out these logs as they were being generated using rsyslog's filter conditions.

1. Open the rsyslog config file in /etc/rsyslog.conf.
2. Paste this rule at the top:

   `#filter out all logs containing the string 'huion'`

   `:syslogtag, contains, "huion" ~`
3. Restart rsyslog with `systemctl restart rsyslog`

The rule defines a property based filter which specifies a property name, a compare operation and a value.
The logs were all being generated with the 'huiontablet.sh' tag; so use 'syslogtag' as the property name. Then use the 'contains' compare-operation to only filter logs who's syslogtag contains the string 'huion'. Finally the '~' indicates this log is to be discarded.

Hope this helps :)